# Component props are not changed when function is called from a child component

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, angular7

When a method is called from a child component, the Propos of parent component are not changed in angular.io.

I have this method in `dashboard.component`:

```
listPeers(){
    this.loading = true;
    this.localStorage.getItem("payload").subscribe( (storage : string) =>{
      this.jwt = storage;
      this.userService.listPeers(this.jwt).subscribe( (res) => {
        this.loading = false;
        if(res.success){
          console.log(res.peers)
          this.peers = res.peers;
          this.listUsersCrm();
        }else{
          this.snackBar.openFromComponent(ToastComponent, {
            data: res.msg
          });
          this.router.navigate(['/notfound']);
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

And on "commit-changes.component" I call this method:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardComponent } from "../dashboard/dashboard.component";

@Component({
  providers: [DashboardComponent],
  selector: 'app-commit-changes',
  templateUrl: './commit-changes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./commit-changes.component.scss']
})
export class CommitChangesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dashBoardComponent : DashboardComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  discardChanges(){
    this.dashBoardComponent.listPeers();
  }


}
```

This method is already called, but the props from parent (dashboard.component) are not changed.

Note: The method `listPeers` is calling API to list peers stored on BD and set peers props.

```
this.peers = res.peers;
```

What's the correctly way to executed this method and apply changes of props?

Comment: You don't inject components. They're components, not providers. What's the relation between your two components ?

Comment: You should use `@Output/@Input` or service to communicate between child and parent.

Comment: "commit-changes" is a component to save or rollback changes applied from dashboard component.
How i could use correctly this method like a component instead a provider?

Comment: @Lends can you show me a example, please?

Comment: @LeandroCastro it should be a service, not a component.

Comment: @LeandroCastro This means it should be decorated with `@Injectable` and providedin your module in the `providers` array, and not decorated with `@Component` and in the `imports` of your module.

Comment: @trichetriche can not i use it like a component? i already this methods working correctly in my "dashboard.component". I just would like call it from another component(a child component).

Comment: @LeandroCastro you could, but that's not how. That's why I have asked you what the relation between those components are. In fact, just [follow the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) to know how to make them communicate.

Comment: Thanks... I will read and try it.

Comment: This works @trichetriche. Thanks, man!!!